# PagSeguro not returning redirect URL

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to set up PagSeguro (brazil's PayPal) and in doing so using [this python library](https://github.com/rochacbruno/python-pagseguro)

I've made a example script to try and get a returned URL, but every time it always returns none. (I'm putting in my real token and email in the script)

```
from pagseguro import PagSeguro


config = {'sandbox': True}

pg = PagSeguro(email="email", token="token", config=config)

pg.sender = {
    "name": "Bruno Rocha",
    "area_code": 11,
    "phone": 981001213,
    "email": "rochacbruno@gmail.com",
}

pg.shipping = {
    "type": pg.SEDEX,
    "street": "Av Brig Faria Lima",
    "number": 1234,
    "complement": "5 andar",
    "district": "Jardim Paulistano",
    "postal_code": "06650030",
    "city": "Sao Paulo",
    "state": "SP",
    "country": "BRA"
}
pg.reference = "00123456789"

pg.items = [
    {"id": "0001", "description": "Produto 1", "amount": 354.20, "quantity": 2, "weight": 200},
    {"id": "0002", "description": "Produto 2", "amount": 50, "quantity": 1, "weight": 1000}
]

pg.redirect_url = "http://meusite.com/obrigado"

pg.notification_url = "http://meusite.com/notification"

response = pg.checkout()
print(response.payment_url)
```

If I try to print the response without the `payment_url` it prints a object but I'm not sure how to parse it either.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

See if doing:

```
print dir(response)   # show the names in the module namespace
print dir(response.payment_url)   # show the names in the module namespace
```

gives you the additional key names you need to get more information.